# Selenium Python 3 TypeError: rect is undefined

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

So i have been trying to fill in text in google.com and press left mouse button on the search button (I know i can fix this by pressing enter on google.com but my real project requires me to press left mouse button, I'm using google.com as a testing page)

My first try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://google.com")
driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("kek")
driver.find_element_by_name("btnK").click()
```

I got an error: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  could not be scrolled into view

After googling and finding a fix for my previous error I edited the code to:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_page_load_timeout("10")

driver.get("https://google.com")
driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("kek")
element = driver.find_element_by_name("btnK")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

I got the following error: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: rect is undefined

Now I have no clue how to fix this error. The button is clearly visible/clickable and the page is fully loaded.

**Edit:**

After trying the fix of x I got the same error: "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: rect is undefined".

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_page_load_timeout("10")

driver.get("https://google.com")
driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("kek")
element = driver.find_element_by_name("btnK")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element)
actions.click()
actions.perform()
```

Comment: Instead of click on button try submit after send_keys()
driver.find_element_by_name("q").submit()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```py
driver.get("https://google.com")
driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("kek")

driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('btnK')[0].click();")
```

Welcome to SO:-)

Comment: So have have tried this, but I am still getting the same error. I have updated my post, see under: "Edit:". I might have edited the code wrong, I'm fairly new to python+ selenium.

Comment: @Grasmat Edit my answer for you!